# Pop/clicking stop audio play NAudio

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, naudio

I create ease audio player synthesizer (audio sample), at playing audio (note file audio) click key button keyboard, playing audio, key button up event, audio stop(). Audio stop() call pop/clicking audio. I try volume down, don't help and pause() don't help.

```cs
IWavePlayer player1;
AudioFileReader audio = new AudioFileReader(
    PathSettings.getProgramPath()
    + "/sounds/C4.wav");

player1 = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
player1.Init(audio);

private void Synthesizer_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Key.Z == e.Key)
    {
        player1.Stop();
    }
}

private void Synthesizer_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Key.Z == e.Key)
    {
        audio.Volume = 1;
        audio.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0);
        player1.Play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like System.Audio or sound, when you right click you might be able to see designer references.

Comment: What kind of library is it? Doesn't find it suitable in my dependencies.

Comment: Ill go find it, if not, try searching online for alternative audio players, try also using the nuget packages, it could have some other alternative options for playing audio.

Comment: I tried uses alternative audio player (Bass, MediaPlayer(WPF), SoundPlayer), pop/clicks at stop(), remained.

Comment: rip ok then, I have no other suggestions right now.